# AWK variable retains its value after piping output into it from system()

Tags: awk, pipe

I want to print the line containing the IP address (may be absent) from the output of: `ifconfig $1`

Nothing should be printed (`output` should be empty) if the command returns nothing.

Here's the command I am using:

```
echo -e "wlan2 \n eth3" | awk '{
                          command = "ifconfig " $1 " | grep \"inet addr\" ";

                          command | getline output;
                          print $1 output;
                               }'
```

Output:

```
wlan2          inet addr:192.168.0.104  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
eth3          inet addr:192.168.0.104  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

In this case, `wlan2` has an IP, `eth3` does **not** have an IP. But the same line gets printed for `eth3`.

**Question:** How to find out if the output of the command is nothing? Or make sure that variable `output` does not retain its previous value in subsequent iterations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you do have a genuine reason to do this in awk (at the moment, it looks like you could do this using the shell), you need to make a couple of changes:

```
awk '{ command = "ifconfig " $1 " | grep \"inet addr\" " }
     command | getline output > 0  { print $1, output }
     { close(command) }'
```

By checking the return value of `getline`, we can only print the line when it is successful. It is also important to use `close` so that the pipe isn't left open, as this will lead to problems with larger inputs or repeated lines.

It seems like piping to `grep` within awk is a bit of an anti-pattern, so you might be better off doing the pattern matching in awk itself:

```
awk '{ command = "ifconfig " $1
     while (command | getline output > 0) if (output ~ /inet addr/) print $1, output }
     { close(command) }'
```

A `while` loop is used to read all of the output of `ifconfig`. If a match is found, the line is printed.